# How to avoid entering ranged mode when parrying?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

Sometimes when parrying an attack, I involuntarily enter ranged mode.
How can I avoid that since it's the same button for both?

Answer (score 6):

The difference is *duration*.  Tap to Parry.  Hold to enter Ranged.

I used to make the same mistake with *Brutalize* until I learned to trust in the Tap & Release.

From a PC user's perspective, the button in question is the Right Mouse Button.

- Hold RMB => Ranged Mode
- Tap RMB while stealthed => Brutalize
- Tap RMB while unstealted => Parry

Perhaps it will help if you think of *Parry* as being triggered by the *release* of the button.

This mechanic allows them to map several abilities to a relatively small number of keys, and is probably more important on game controllers than it is on a PC.