# How to disable/work around glaive ruining the combat in Middle Earth: Shadow of War?

Tags: keyboard, middle-earth-shadow-of-war

I am playing on PC, the default control binding for attack is <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd> for glaive it is `holding` <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd>.

My issue is that instead of doing normal attacks, my character starts casting glaive many times which messes up my attacks! What is even worse is if I hold the glaive just to use it so it would go away, I usually end up being hit by enemies due not countering.

I can't seem to find the way to rebind only the glaive input (holding <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd>). When I try to bind it (lets say to <kbd>T</kbd>, which isn't bound to anything) the game then asks me if I want to rebind another 20+ inputs that are bound to holding <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd>. I obviously don't, but if I click cancel to this second prompt then control stays unchanged.

**How do I disable/work around glaive ruining combat?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back when I was playing Shadow of Mordor, I had a similar problem with the Right Mouse button.  I'd enter ranged mode when trying to Parry or Brutalize.  See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278942/how-to-avoid-entering-ranged-mode-when-parrying/278943#278943).

The trick is to change your thinking.  Much like ranged attacks or parries, Melee Attacks are triggered by the *release* of the button.  Quick release = Sword, Delayed release = Glaive.  An added advantage of training yourself to get off the Left mouse button is that you are in a better place to take advantage of the *Elven Precision* upgrade to the *Critical Strike* skill.

If you can Parry without entering Ranged Mode, then you can swing a sword without charging your Glaive.